# Error in sum(x[i:(i + 50)], na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: sum, sliding, invalid-characters

I am new in R , and I am trying to do a script to calculate the sliding mean of some data.

This is how my data looks like:

Timestamp        `Accelerometer X` `Accelerometer Y` `Accelerometer Z`
                                        
1 121219.757080078 -5.66180946541818 8.85684119781125  1.65407075345669 
2 121239.288330078 -7.38255951126451 9.4117333531527   1.44410517346543

it has around 6000 rows, and I need to calculate the mean of Accelerometer x, Accelerometer Y, and Accelerometer Z each fifty rows. So from the data of row 1 to 50 I must get the mean of the 3 variables, then from rows 51 to 100, and so on until row 6000.

I tried with (for the first variable):

```
library(reshape2)
library(reshape)
x <- deadlift$`Accelerometer X`
win.size <- 50
slide <- 50
results <- data.frame(index=numeric(),win.mean=numeric())
i<-1
j<-1
while (i<length(x)) {
  win.mean<-sum(x[i:(i+50)],na.rm = TRUE)/win.size
  results[j,]<-c(i,win.mean)
  i<-i+slide
  j<-j+1
}
```

but I get this message:

Error in sum(x[i:(i + 50)], na.rm = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument

any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

the problem was that the object x was created as character. I converted it to numeric with as.numeric.

It worked.

Regards,